# Disable Spacebar Acting as Enter on Dialogs

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, compiz, dialog

Sometimes I will be typing and a dialog will appear on my screen right as I am hitting space. This causes the dialog to execute its focused button and disappear leaving me wondering what I just did. I don't think it's a matter of preventing windows from appearing on top of other windows (although if that is the only solution I could try that). I feel like the fix is preventing the spacebar acting like enter with dialog buttons. Is there a way with compiz or something to alter that functionality? I am on ubuntu 14.04.